# MS Project, Custom Field to show Completed Tasks with Lag

Tags: ms-project

Is it possible to create a custom field that tests if a completed task has a predecessor or successor with lag?

Update:
I've solved my problem bellow.

I had inherited a large project which had not been properly progressed in some time and whose execution logic had changed significantly since the last baseline. To get up to speed I was creating a few custom fields to help identify tasks to watch when picking it apart and putting it back together again. My predecessor had included a lot of lag in his linkages, which a) I didn't want to progress and b) I wanted move into clearer to understand tasks rather than keep in the linkages.

Comment: Welcome to PMSE! This type of question is certainly on-topic as long as you provide sufficient background. Please improve your question by describing what you've already tried, and why that didn't work for you.

Comment: Hey Trigger, welcome to PMSE! The main idea in the request for more information in the question is simply to help others with the same problem find it from Google. It looks like you have an answer, which is great. Sometimes askers wonder how they can give back when they're only asking questions. On our site, we really value questions and question-askers, so the more information, the better. Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quickly filter tasks that have lead or lag using autofilters on the predecessor and/or successor field.  Use **contains +** to filter for tasks with lag.  You can apply autofilters to multiple fields (columns) to further narrow down whether the task is complete (filter on % complete field).

Comment: This worked for what I needed at the time, but I also was looking to create a graphical indicator test (which I wasn't clear about in the original question and have updated above, and bellow).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response.
This is the test I was actually trying to construct.

This is used to check if a task with 100% completion has a Predecessor or Successor with lag.

I'll edit the original question to be more specific.

```
IIf(
    ((InStr(1,[Predecessors],'+') Or InStr(1,[Predecessors],'-')) 
    Or 
    (InStr(1,[Successors],'+') Or InStr(1,[Successors],'-'))<>0)
    And 
    [% Complete]=100,1,0
    )
```

*Formatted for readability.